# Firefox Always renders <a> on a separate line

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have some pretty simple HTML and CSS stuff going on here and in Chrome and Internet Explorer it works great, however Firefox just like a toddler can't seem to draw within the lines.

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="Profile_Summary">
    <div id="1984" class="Profile_Summary_Text">
        <h4>Sherlock Holmes</h4><br/>
        221B Baker St.<br/>
        Private Detective<br/>" +
        <span>Scotland Yard <a href=\"mailto:sherlock.holmes@nomail.com\">[Email]</a></span>
</div>
    </div>
```

here is the CSS

```
.Profile_Summary{
    height:262px;
    width:224px;
    border:solid 1px;
    float:left;
    margin:15px 0px 15px 25px;
    background-size:100%;
    background-size:cover;
    border-radius:5px;
}

.Profile_Summary_Text{
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .65);
    padding:0px 0px 0px 6px;/*top right bottom left*/
    height:75px;/*100-9 to adjust for padding-top*/
    width:218px;/*294px;/*300-6 to adjust for padding-left*/
    margin-top:188px;/*250px;/*350 - height(as seen above)*/
    font-size:15px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-radius:5px;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}

.Email{
    float:right;
    padding-right:4px;
}
```

The issue I am having is the [Email] text in the `<a>` does not appear on the same line as the Text immediately before it. For example you have something like

```
Scotland Yard
                    [Email]
```

It only happens with Firefox though, and since the Profile_Summary_Text hides overflow the `<a>` tag is never accessible.

In case it makes a difference I'll also say I am loading multiple of the Profile_Summary divs to a page dynamically. I have tried changing the `<span>` into `<div>` and a `<p>` but neither fixed it. I also set padding and margin to 0% for both the `<span>` and `<a>`. I've also tried a bunch of different combination of `display:inline` and `display:inline-block` etc. for the `<span>` and `<a>` but nothing seems to correct this behavior.

This isn't the first time I've had trouble with Firefox recently so I'm also a little curious if some kind of update was made that messed up their rendering rules. My Primary question is what can I do to fix this?

Comment: Curious why this got a downvote. Would have been nice to have gotten a comment explaining it. Thanks @Av Ant for answering the question you were super helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your html to"

```
<div class="Profile_Summary">
    <div id="1984" class="Profile_Summary_Text">
    <h4>Sherlock Holmes</h4><br/>
        221B Baker St.<br/>
        Private Detective<br/>" + 
    <span><a href=\"mailto:sherlock.holmes@nomail.com\">[Email]</a>Scotland Yard </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

In other word, move the email anchor to the beginning of the span(its container).

Float elements must come before other elements in order for contents to warp around it, though it's a little counter-intuitive when the float is right.

Edit: edited the position of the anchor, I copied the text incorrectly.

Comment: Can I get a screenshot or image of the desired result? It's hard to imagine what you want with only that...

Comment: I changed it after you edited your answer and it worked.

Comment: Cool, glad to help :)